# Problem using System.Linq to print a file line by line (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, string, linq

So I'm writing a very simple way to display graphics content in a text file (Just unicode symbols) line by line, at a certain distance from the console edge.

```
GraphicsDraw:
int GraphicsDrawCount = 0;
do
{
    Console.SetCursorPosition(3, 3 + GraphicsDrawCount);

    TempMemory = Convert.ToString(File
      .ReadLines("F:\\Assets\\StartScreen.txt")
      .Skip(GraphicsDrawCount)
      .Take(1)+"");

    Console.WriteLine(TempMemory);
    GraphicsDrawCount++;
} while (GraphicsDrawCount < 19);
```

I expected it to actually give me the lines in question but instead it constantly outputs

> System.Linq.Enumerable+EnumerablePartition`1[System.String] .

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: `File.ReadLines(...)` returns *several* lines; you may want join them insead of converting: `TempMemory = string.Join("; ", File.ReadLines(...)...);`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko That just throws this error instead:
CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'char'

Comment: You are re-reading that file on every iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate cause of misbehavior is that

```
File
  .ReadLines("F:\\Assets\\StartScreen.txt")
  .Skip(GraphicsDrawCount)
  .Take(1)
```

returns not a `string`, but enumeration `IEnumerable<string>`; so the quick but *dirty* amendment is to change `.Take(1)` into `.FirstOrDefault("")`: we want a single string, not a enumeration of strings with one item.

```
...
// No need of Convert here
TempMemory = File
  .ReadLines("F:\\Assets\\StartScreen.txt")
  .Skip(GraphicsDrawCount)
  .FirstOrDefault(""); // <- The very first item, instead of Take(1)
...
```

A better approach is to redesign the code (the loop and everything). If you want to print `19` top lines you can *just join them*:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, File
  .ReadLines("F:\\Assets\\StartScreen.txt")
  .Take(19)));
```